# Copy range values into array without for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy Range values into an array, and then copy the array into new range like below.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Range("A1:A3").Value
Range("C1:E1").Value = Arr
End Sub
```

But, the result is as below.

[image]

What's wrong with this code?

Are there any ways to tranfer range values into new range without for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Transpose()

Replace this line

```
Range("C1:E1").Value = Arr
```

With

```
Range("C1:E1").Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
```